# Proving $\forall x(x \text{ is odd} \to x^2 \text{ is odd)}$ using First Order Logic.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

*Symbolization key*: We define:

- $O(x)$: $x$ is odd.

*Proof*:

$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\def\Ae#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ai#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall I} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ee#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ei#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists I} \: #1 \\}
\def\R#1{\qquad\mathbf{R} \: #1 \\}
\def\ii#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ie#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to E} \: #1 \\}
\def\be#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow E} \: #1 \\}
\def\be#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow E} \: #1 \\}
\def\qe#1{\qquad\mathbf{=E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ne#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg E} \: #1 \\}
\def\IP#1{\qquad\mathbf{IP} \: #1 \\}
\def\x#1{\qquad\mathbf{X} \: #1 \\}
$
$
\fitch{1.\, \forall x \exists y(O(x) \leftrightarrow (x = 2y+1)}{
 \fitch{2.\, O(a)}{
 3.\, \exists y(O(a) \leftrightarrow a = 2y+1) \Ae{1}
 \fitch{4.\, O(a) \leftrightarrow a = 2k+1}{
 5.\, a = 2k+1 \be{4,2}
 6.\, a^2 = (2k+1)^2 \quad Leibniz\, 5\\
 7.\, a^2 = 2(2k^2+2k)+1 \quad arithmetic\,  6\\
 \fitch{8.\, c = 2k^2+2k}{
 9.\, a^2 = 2c+1 \qe{8,7}
 \ldots \\
}\\
\ldots
}\\
m. O(a^2)
}\\
m+1.\,O(a) \to O(a^2)\\
m+2.\, \forall x(O(x) \to O(x^2)) \Ai{m+1}
}
$

I do not know how can I discharge the assumption made on line 8. Am I heading in the right direction ?

---

EDIT: based on @Magdiragdag suggestions, I modified the proof to arrive at this one.

$
\fitch{1.\, \forall x (O(x) \leftrightarrow \exists y(x = 2y+1))}{
 \fitch{2.\, O(a)}{
 3.\, O(a) \leftrightarrow \exists y(a = 2y+1) \Ae{1}
 4.\, \exists y(a = 2y+1) \be{3}
 \fitch{5.\, a = 2k+1}{
 6.\, a^2 = (2k+1)^2 \quad Leibniz\, 5\\
 7.\, a^2 = 2(2k^2+2k)+1 \quad arithmetic\,  6\\
 8.\, \exists y(a^2=2y+1) \Ei{8}
 9.\, O(a^2) \leftrightarrow \exists y(a^2=2y+1) \Ae{1}
 10.\, O(a^2) \be{10,9}
}\\
11. O(a^2)
}\\
12.\,O(a) \to O(a^2) \ii{2-12}
13.\, \forall x(O(x) \to O(x^2)) \Ai{13}
}
$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interpretation of $O(x)$ at line 1 is wrong. It's not $\forall x \exists y [ O(x) \leftrightarrow x = 2 y + 1]$, but $\forall x [ O(x) \leftrightarrow \exists y[x = 2y + 1]]$.

Additionally, there is no need to assuming anything at line 8. You can directly use $\exists I$ after line 7 to conclude $\exists y [ a^2 = 2 y + 1]$. Then use the characterisation of $O(x)$ again to conclude $O(a^2)$.

Comment: Thanks, @Magdiragdag. But how can I discharge the assumption on line 8? I get no benefit from applying →, for example.

Comment: There is no need to assume anything there; you can just conclude $\exists y[a^2 + 2y+1]$ directly after line 7. (Also, what is happening at line 8 is that you're _assuming_ that $c$ equals $2k^2 + 2k$, but there is no $c$ in your formula. What you want is _define_ $c$ to be $2k^2 + 2k$.)

Comment: Thank you, @Magdiragdag. I edited the post. Do you think it is correct, now ?

Comment: Looks ok. I don't know how your system deals with introducing abbreviations like you do in line 8, but it seems reasonable. You can drop that line, though.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking about that. My system does not deal with abbreviations. It is the only solution that occurs to me since I don't think it's possible to replace an expression like $2k+2k^2$ as if it were a variable to apply $\mathbf{\exists I}$. Are you thinking of abstracting what's inside the parenthesis ?

Comment: Given a formula $\phi(y)$ (i.e., a formula $\phi$ in which the variable $y$ appears freely) and a term (i.e., expression) $t$, you can conclude $\exists y [ \phi(y) ]$ from $\phi(t)$. This is $\exists I$ and there is no need for $t$ to be a variable.

Comment: And if your system doesn't allow for abbreviations, then what is it that you are doing in line 8? That looked like the introduction of an abbreviation to me.

Comment: You’re right. I used that notation because didn’t know another method of using Existential Introduction. Thanks for your explanation about the concept of term ! I will drop that line in the proof.

Comment: Do you have some book in mind where that definition of Existential Introduction is mentioned ? Seems interesting.